# How to set up multy-user xrdp server for 20 users that would force kill-all session created processes on disconnect?

Tags: remote, remote-desktop

I want to have an xrdp multy-user server that would allow 20 users to connect. I wish to kill-all session created processes (and terminate sesstion) on disconnect for each user. Is it possible with xrdp?